# Floating Menu Is Not Working Within IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I was using floating-1.12.js library to make a left Menu float when scrolling up or down, and this is working as expected, however a requirement changed by the client to make that page hosted within an iframe on other website that he owns, so both sites are on same domain but the one having the floating menu will be loaded inside an iframe on the other site.

So I noticed that the floating menu functionality is not working anymore and an error in the browser console appears as the following:

[image]

So I checked the official site of that library and I notice that if I put their demo inside an iframe I got same error:

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="1000px" src="http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating/confined_demo.html" />

</body>
</html>
```

So in the above code if you take the link and paste it in the browser you will see the demo working as expected, but putting it inside an iframe will be blocked.

How can I deal with this problem?
Please Advise.

Comment: The error results from this line, `var iframes = window.top.document.body.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME");` - you can not access the document of a different frame/window, when the content of that frame was loaded from a different origin. But that is of course for the scenario, where they _are_ loaded from different origins. You say that was not the case, but the error message suggests otherwise ...?

Comment: Actually I mentioned that the are on same domain (sub-domain) but not same origine, each site has different hosting

Comment: Origin in terms of HTTP does not refer to where stuff is hosted, but to the scheme, host and port of the URL - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin

Comment: _"Actually I mentioned that the are on same domain (sub-domain)"_ - yes, you mentioned it, but you are being very vague here. And both actually served from the same hostname, or one or both of them served from a subdomain, those are different things. If you feel the need to block out relevant information in your screenshot, then please at least give us a _proper_ explanation of the setup, using names like `example.com`, and `sub.example.com` for a subdomain. So, what is from where _exactly_ now here?

Comment: A way to half-way work around such origin issues when it comes to subdomains, is, or rather was, `document.domain` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain You might still have success with setting that, but there is no way of telling when this will stop working.

Comment: @CBroe, sorry for the delay on reply, well you are correct, I missed adding the info, lets say first site is parent.mydomain.org and the second is child.mydomain.org

Comment: I was trying to check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain but actually I did not understand what I should change?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain#setting_the_domain - if you set `document.domain = "mydomain.org";` in both pages, then they should be able to access each other's DOM.